# Python process not running in paralell

Tags: python

I have a very simple process and it seems its not running in paralell.

Heres an example to illustrate that:

```
class BattleQueueProcess(Process):

def __init__(self):
    self._runWorker = True
    super(Process, self).__init__()

def run(self):
    while self._runWorker:
        print('loop')
        time.sleep(1)

def stop(self):
    self._runWorker = False
    self.join()
    self.terminate()
```

So i have this following code.

```
print('starting')
process = BattleQueueProcess()
process.start()
print('started')
```

However my output is

´starting´
´loop´
´loop´
´loop´
... and so on

´started´ is never printed.

Why is the process not running in parallel ?

Comment: It looks like you are only starting one process. You need more than one process in order to have parallel processing.

Comment: dont i have the main process ?? I wanted a subprocess of that main to be started in paralell

Comment: It is running in parallel to the main process. Why do you think it isn;t?

Comment: It;s easier to see what is going on if you add `time.sleep(1)` to your print loop.

Comment: i did that =(  'started' is never printed :(

Comment: Odd, when I run your code (with the sleep), I do see the 'started' print. What is your hardware and OS?

Comment: windows 8, pretty good hardware -.-
my main thread is inside a flask app, might that be the problem ?

Comment: If I put the 'started' print in a loop, I see intermixed 'loop' and 'started' prints (even without any sleeps). Give something like that a try.

Comment: I am running on Ubuntu, so that may be a difference. Also, the same code fails for me under Python 2.7, but works fine under Python 3.6. Do you see any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

In your `BattleQueueProcess` class, there is an error in the `__init__()` method. Your call to `super` should be:

```
super(BattleQueueProcess, self).__init__()
```

not:

```
super(Process, self).__init__()
```